# UnboundLocalError in python confusing

Tags: python

Could anyone explain the exception the below code. It only works when I change the var sub in the display() to another name. There is no global variable sub as well. So what happened ?

```
def sub(a, b):
    return a - b

def display():
    sub = sub(2,1) // if change to sub1 or sth different to sub, it works
    print sub
```

Comment: Initially, `sub` is a function. Then, it becomes the return value of a function. So when you say `print sub`, python doesn't know which `sub` you are referring to

Comment: @inspectorG4dget: your explanation very straightforward. thanks

Answer (score 2):

Any variable you assign to inside a scope is treated as a local variable (unless you declare it `global`, or, in python3, `nonlocal`), which means it is not looked up in the surrounding scopes.

A simplified example with the same error:

```
def a(): pass

def b(): a = a()
```

Now, consider the different scopes involved here:

The global namespace contains `a` and `b`.

The function `a` contains no local variables.

The function `b` contains an assignment to `a` - this means it is interpreted as a local variable and shadows the function `a` from the outer scope (in this case, the global scope). As `a` has not been defined inside of `b` before the call, it is an unbound local variable, hence the UnboundLocalError. This is exactly the same as if you had written this:

```
def b(): x = x()
```

The solution to this is simple: choose a different name for the result of the `sub` call.

It is important to note that the order of use and assignment makes no difference - the error would have still happened if you wrote the function like this:

```
def display():
    value = sub(2,1)         #UnboundLocalError here...
    print value
    sub = "someOtherValue"   #because you assign a variable named `sub` here
```

This is because the list of local variables is generated when the python interpreter creates the function object.

Comment: so the unbound error comes from the call to the function because it is first shadowed by the previous assignement? is it the same if x (local variable) is assigned to any value, and then x (function) is called ?

Comment: The error is that the your function contains an assignment to `sub` so sub is treated as a local variable. And you try to use this local variable during the initial assignment while it doesn't have a value yet.

Answer (score 1):

This was originally a comment. The OP found this useful as an answer. Therefore, I am re-posting it as an answer

Initially, `sub` is a function. Then, it becomes the return value of a function. So when you say `print sub`, python doesn't know which `sub` you are referring to.

**Edit**:

First you define a function `sub`. Now, python knows what `sub` is.

When you create a variable and try to assign to it (say `x = 2`), python evaluates the stuff on the right hand side of the `=` and assigns the value of the evaluation as the value of the stuff on the left hand side of the `=`. Thus, everything on the right hand side should actually compute.

So if your statement was `x = x+1`, then `x` better have a value assigned to it before that line; and the previously defined `x` has to be of some type compatible with the addition of `1`.

But suppose `x` is a function, and you make a variable called `x` in some other function, and try to assign to it, a value computed with function `x`, then this really starts to confuse python about which `x` you are referring to. This is really an oversimplification of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12092094/198633), which does a much better job of explaining variable scope and shadowing in python functions

Comment: This is overly simplified - if you said `sub = 1` inside `display` you still shadow the function name, which is perfectly legal. The problem is that the name is *used* and *assigned to* in the same scope. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12092094/1110381) for a more detailed explanation of closures in python.

Comment: @l4mpi: fair enough. I really should stop answering questions on Monday mornings before my coffee kicks in. Thank you for the clarification

Answer (score 1):

For every variable used, Python determines whether it is a local or a nonlocal variable. Referencing a unknown variable marks it as nonlocal. Reusing the same name as a local variable later is considered a programmers mistake.

Consider this example:

```
def err():
    print x # this line references x
    x = 3   # this line creates a local variable x
err()
```

This gives you

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "asd.py", line 5, in <module>
    err()
  File "asd.py", line 2, in err
    print x # this line references x
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'x' referenced before assignment
```

What happens is basically that Python keeps track of all references to names in code. When it reads  the line `print x` Python knows that `x` is a variable from a outer scope (upvalue or global). However, in `x = 3` the `x` is used as a local variable. As this is a inconsistency in the code, Python raises an `UnboundLocalError` to get the Programmers attention.

Answer (score -1):

Python start executing your code and get the function first

```
def sub(a, b):
    return a - b
```

So after executing this interpreter get the `sub` as a function. Now when come to next line it found

```
def display():
    sub = sub(2,1) // if change to sub1 or sth different to sub, it works
    print sub
```

so first line `sub = sub (2, 1)` will convert the `sub` function to `sub` variable. From this function you are returning the `sub` variable. So its create problem.