# Python inner functions

Tags: python

In python, I can write :

```
def func():
    x = 1
    print x
    x+=1

    def _func():
        print x
    return _func

test = func()
test()
```

when I run it, the output is :

**1**

**2**

As _func has access to the "x" variable defined in func. Right...

But if I do :

```
def func():
    x = 1
    print x

    def _func():
        x+=1
        print x
    return _func

test = func()
test()
```

Then I got an error message : **UnboundLocalError: local variable 'x' referenced before assignment**

In this case, it seems that _func cannot "see" the "x" variable

**The question is:** Why does print x in the first example "see" the "x" variable, whereas the mathematical operator x+=1 throws an exception?

I don't understand why...

Comment: This is why python 3 added `nonlocal`

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5218895/python-nested-functions-variable-scoping

Comment: I usually use an object to store context because you can modify the object's properties within the closure. Ex: `x = {'val': 0}` then `x['val'] += 1` inside the `_func`.

Comment: And another interesting [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1261875/python-nonlocal-statement).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13277359/1419123  This specifically addresses whats going on with the print function and why it can access x in one case and not in the other.

Comment: This is a duplicate of many other questions, e.g. [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5218895/python-nested-functions-variable-scoping) and [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12091973/python-closure-with-assigning-outer-variable-inside-inner-function). Searching for `UnboundLocalError` on this site would have pointed you to the answer. The [first google result](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/05/15/understanding-unboundlocalerror-in-python/) for "python UnboundLocalError" also explains what happens in detail. Please do some research before asking a question next time...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [UnboundLocalError with nested function scopes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2609518/unboundlocalerror-with-nested-function-scopes)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/293097/1741450

> Variables in scopes other than the local function's variables can be accessed, but can't be rebound to new parameters without further syntax. Instead, assignment will create a new local variable instead of affecting the variable in the parent scope. For example:

Comment: yep : print only access x (and it can) whereas in the second example the function is trying to modify x (and it can't according to my quote).

Answer (score 3):

Considering that Python is an "interpreted" language, one naturally assumes that if a variable is already defined in an outer scope that same variable should still be accessible in the inner scope.  And indeed in your first example when the inner `_func` merely prints `x` it works.

The thing that's non-obvious about Python though is that this is not exactly how the scope of a variable is determined.  Python analyzes at *compile* time which variables should be considered "local" to a scope based on whether they're assigned to within that scope.  In this case assignment includes augmented assignment operators.  So when Python compiles your inner `_func` in the second example to bytecode it sees the `x += 1` and determines that `x` must be a local variable to `_func`.  Except of course since its first assignment is an augmented assignment there is no `x` variable locally to augment and you get the `UnboundLocalError`.

A different way to see this might be to write something like:

```
def _func():
    print x
    x = 2
```

Here again because `_func` contains the line `x = 2` it will treat `x` as a local variable in the scope of that function and *not* as the `x` defined in the outer function.  So the `print x` should also result in an `UnboundLocalError`.

You can examine this in deeper detail by using the [`dis`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/dis.html) module to display the bytecode generated for the function:

```
>>> dis.dis(_func)
  2           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (x)
              3 PRINT_ITEM          
              4 PRINT_NEWLINE       

  3           5 LOAD_CONST               1 (2)
              8 STORE_FAST               0 (x)
             11 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             14 RETURN_VALUE
```

The `LOAD_FAST` opcode is for intended for "fast" lookups of local variables that bypasses slower, more general name lookups.  It uses an array of pointers where each local variable (in the current stack frame) is associated with an index in that array, rather than going through dictionary lookups and such.  In the above example the sole argument to the `LOAD_FAST` opcode is `0`--in this case the first (and only) local.

You can check on the function itself (specifically its underlying code object) that there is one local variable used in that code, and that the variable name associated with it is `'x'`:

```
>>> _func.__code__.co_nlocals
1
>>> _func.__code__.co_varnames
('x',)
```

That's how `dis.dis` is able to report `0 LOAD_FAST                0 (x)`.  Likewise for the `STORE_FAST` opcode later on.

None of this is necessary to know in order to understand variable scopes in Python, but it can be helpful nonetheless to know what's going on under the hood.

As already mentioned in some other answers, Python 3 introduced the `nonlocal` keyword which prevents this compile-time binding of names to local variables based on assignment to that variable in the local scope.

Answer (score 0):

You can't rebind variables that are closed over in Python 2 (you can use `nonlocal` in Python 3). If I have to do what you're doing in Python 2 then I do the following workaround:

```
class Pointer(object):
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val = val

def func():
    px = Pointer(1)
    print px.val
    px.val += 1

    def _func():
        print px.val
    return _func

test = func()
test()
```

Basically I put whatever values I need to be mutated onto an object - sometimes I use a list with one element - and then re-write the code so that all that happens is method calls. The above is actually equivalent to:

```
class Pointer(object):
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val = val

def func():
    px = Pointer(1)
    print px.val
    px.__setattr__('val', px.val + 1)

    def _func():
        print px.val
    return _func

test = func()
test()
```