# Calling function f from within f

Tags: python

I'm making a small program to convert binary numbers to hexadecimal. To go about this, I first split the given data into 4 bit chunks as you can see.

```
def binary_to_hex(n):
    if len(n)%4 != 0:
        n = "0"+n
        return binary_to_hex(n)
    return n
```

Now this example works without a hitch, returning chunks of four bits.

However, when I omit the first `return` statement inside the `if` clause, only ever one `0` gets added. If `n` is not divisible by 4, that is.

I'm guessing it has something to do with variable scope. [Similar problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18616084/python-inner-functions) don't seem to apply in this case. **Can you explain what is going on and how one would go about without using the first return statement.**

Also, what is the name of this type of function, that calls *itself* until it satisfies a given requirement ?

Comment: It's called a recursive function.

Comment: that's not a "binary number". it's a string, and all you're doing is zero-padding it. and the name would be "recursive". **ANY** function which calls itself directly (or indirectly) is recursive.

Comment: I left the binary to string conversion out for simplicity sake. In any case, it is just a sequence of 0's and 1's.

Comment: For more info on recursive functions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3021/what-is-recursion-and-when-should-i-use-it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code we're discussing:

```
def binary_to_hex(n):
    if len(n)%4 != 0:
        n = "0"+n
        binary_to_hex(n)  # no `return'
    return n
```

Here, `binary_to_hex(n)` calls the function *and ignores the result*. Since the call has no observable side effects (i.e. it doesn't *do* anything that the caller can observe), it is effectively a no-op, and the code is equivalent to:

```
def binary_to_hex(n):
    if len(n)%4 != 0:
        n = "0"+n
    return n
```

This explains the behaviour you're seeing.

> [H]ow one would go about without using the first return statement[?]

Try using a loop or the string repetition operator (`*`).

Comment: Should it not however make changes to the argument n ? My understanding is that n can be treated like a variable, say you make the same changes to a variable that is defined before this function is called, would it not output something else ?

Comment: "Should it not however make changes to the argument n ? " Every **call to** the function (even if other calls are in progress) has its own `n`.

Answer (score 0):

As has been stated in the comments already, a function calling itself is called recursive.

If you want to implement this function without recursion, replace the `if` with a `while`:

```
def add_leading_zeros_to_make_length_of_string_a_multiple_of_four(n):
    while len(n)%4 != 0:
        n = "0"+n
    return n
```