# Nested function definitions and scope (UnboundLocalError)

Tags: python, function, variables, scope

Why is the following code invalid:

```
def foo1(x=5):
    def bar():
        if x == 5:
            x = 6
        print(x)
    bar()
```

While this code is valid:

```
def foo2(x=5):
    def bar():
        if x == 5:
            print('ok')
        print(x)
    bar()
```

`foo2()` will do exactly what you expect, but `foo1()` will give a `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'x' referenced before assignment` at the line `if x == 5:`. Why does altering the value of x later on in the code make this conditional invalid?

Comment: Python first looks for assignment operations in the code. From the moment that happens, it is considered a local variable, that is indeed a (not so very elegant) result from that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python inner functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18616084/python-inner-functions)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Python needs first to **detect what variables are local**, and which variable are fetched from an outer scope. In order to do that **it looks for assignments**, like:

```
def foo1(x=5):
    def bar():
        if x == 5:
            x = 6 # an assignment, so local variable
        print(x)
    bar()
```

The point is, that the assignment can **happen anywhere**. For instance on the last line. Nevertheless, from the moment there is an assignment somewhere `x` is local. So in your first code fragment, `x` is a local variable. But you fetch it before it is assigned (bounded), so Python will error on it.

In [python-3.x](/questions/tagged/python-3.x) you can use the **`nonlocal` keyword** to access `x` from an outer scope:

```
def foo1(x=5):
    def bar():
        nonlocal x
        if x == 5:
            x = 6
        print(x)
    bar()
```

For [python-2.x](/questions/tagged/python-2.x), you can for instance **assign the variable to the function**, like:

```
def foo1(x=5):
    def bar():
        if bar.x == 5:
            bar.x = 6
        print(bar.x)
    bar.x = x
    bar()
```

Note however that the two are **not equivalent**. Since in the former if you alter `x`, it will be alter the `x` in the `foo1` scope as well. In the latter example you only modify `bar.x`. Of course if these are mutable objects, you alter the same object.